# (cmake_minimum_required): CMake 3.15 or higher is required while flutter windows running

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, cmake

i'm trying to run my flutter app on windows but i get the following error :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/printing/windows/CMakeLists.txt:15 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.15 or higher is required.  You are running version
  3.14.19050301-MSVC_2


Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

what I tried is to download the Cmake from the SDK tools but still get the same error

[image]